# Why are gold-sulfur bonds so stable?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

In my analytical chemistry book, I have seen that molecules' electrical conductance has been measured by putting sulfur-containing groups on them and using atomic force microscopy with a gold surface. They say that this works very well because of gold and sulfur's special affinity for one another. I know that thiols and disulfides will be very attracted to gold, forming very stable bonds. Why is this?

Comment: Because they form really stable $\ce{Au4^{2+}}$ cation. see [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1521-3749(200109)627:9%3C2112::AID-ZAAC2112%3E3.0.CO;2-2/epdf) and [this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=IvGnUAaSqOsC&pg=PA359&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: I found one more paper although less attractive - http://library.lanl.gov/cgi-bin/getfile?rc000062.pdf